# using dotcloud env variables in nginx.conf

Tags: dotcloud

dotcloud provides lots of useful information as environment variables but my `nginx.conf` cannot access environment variables.  What's a good way around this?

Here's the scenario: I'd like to redirect certain URLs from my `www` static service to my `rest` service, so I'm currently hardcoding the target URL into `nginx.conf`.  I'd rather use the `DOTCLOUD_REST_HTTP_HOST` variable since that would allow my service to easily migrate.

Comment: Are dotCloud disabling access to the `env` conf instruction? http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#env

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good case for using the `postinstall` script for your service.
dotCloud provides [build hooks](http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/hooks/#post-install) for running at each stage of the push and deploy cycle, and the `postinstall` hook runs last, where it has access to all your environment variables. You could read the variables from `~/environment.json` or from the actual environment (the file is slightly more dependable, since what gets put into the environment may vary by service type, for historical reasons).

Here is an example `dotcloud.yml`:

```
www:
   approot: www
   type: static
   environment:
     LIMITRATEVAR: 2k
```

and an example `nginx.conf` (found in www/nginx.conf):

```
# limitratevar should get set in dotcloud.yml's environment section
# or via `dotcloud env set limitratevar` if you want to set it for all services.
# And then use a postinstall script to update this nginx.conf with sed
limit_rate LIMITRATEVAR;
```

and finally, the example `postinstall` (found in www/postinstall) where read the value of $LIMITRATEVAR out of the environment and update nginx.conf with `sed`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# files named "postinstall" will get run automatically when the code is deployed
# to the container where your service runs.
# See:
# http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/build-file/#prebuild-postbuild-postinstall-build-hooks
# http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/hooks/#post-install

# Make sure we error-out if there are any problems
set -e
echo "Updating the limit_rate to $LIMITRATEVAR"
sed -i.original "s/LIMITRATEVAR/$LIMITRATEVAR/g" ~/current/nginx.conf
echo "nginx.conf updated. Original stored in nginx.conf.original"
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution [here](http://nginx.2469901.n2.nabble.com/Want-to-access-UNIX-environment-variable-td7584005.html) works for some, which isn't to say there may be some issue implementing it on DotCloud, but it's worth a go if you haven't tried it.

At top config level:

```
 env MYVAR;
```

At http level:

```
 perl_set $myvar 'sub { return $ENV{"MYVAR"}; }';
```

Then, for example, at server level:

```
 root $myvar;
```

Comment: DotCloud is including my `nginx.conf` file inside a globally-specified `server {}` block.  Since I'm not in control of top-level configuration, I can't use the `env` directive.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case I've got nothing, sorry.

Comment: You'll need to talk to whoever is in control, then :)